# Inserting a timestamp into postgresql db

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I am using ruby to access a postgresql DB and update it. One of the fields I am attempting to update is called "updated_at" and is of type timestamp without timezone. I am using the statement:

```
db.prepare('statement1', "INSERT INTO games (game_hash,team1,team2,team1score,team2score,time,update_at) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7)");
update = Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
db.exec_prepared('statement1', [myId, team1, team1score, team2, team2score, progress, update]);
```

The update variable is formatted correctly as I was originally getting the not formatted correctly for timestamp field error, but no longer do. BUT the database shows the updated_at field as empty!! All the other field are populated correctly. Anyone know what is causing this?

*UPDATE* - I added a new column of type datetime called last_update and, using that column instead, my timestamps get properly added to the database! I guess because the database originally came from a rails activerecord the update/created_at fields are protected somehow. Thanks for everyones help in trying to resolve this, I'll just use my new column instead.

Comment: Your sql inserts only `created_at` field. I don't see `updated_at`.

Comment: created_at and updated_at are both of type timestamp without timezone, I've tried inserting into each of them and they both come back blank (edited the question to show updated_at in the statement anyways)

Comment: Is it just ruby or are you using Activerecord/Rails? Activerecord manages created_at and updated_at internally.

Comment: The database was originally from a sqlite3 database managed by rails. I migrated it to a postgresql DB. I am updating the DB from outside the rails application because I am using beanstalkd/stalker to run background tasks(where this is being done). Does this mean that since I am outside the rails environment I can't update these fields? I guess I could always just add a new field of type timestamp if that's the case?

Comment: There's no way for a timestamp column to contain "empty" value - it's either NULL or a valid timestamp.

Comment: @MatthewErtel - No, if you are detached it from ActiveRecord, I dont see a reason for not being able to insert values directly. Its only when you are using ActiveRecord to insert/update, you need to consider what I said. Let me play around with it a bit.

Comment: Milen- I am using pgadmin3 to view the db and the fields are blank when viewing the table, so they must be NULL. Srikanth- I'll be messing around with it more today myself but please let me know if you do discover anything. I'll probably try to add a new timestamp field that wasn't created because of ActiveRecord and see if I can insert into it. Thanks!!

Comment: Instead of "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" as your format string, try "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S" and see if that doesn't work.

Comment: @thisfeller using the format you suggested I receive the Exception PGError -> ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "20130321 28:12:53" I do not receive this error when using the format I have, which is why I believe it to be an acceptable timestamp format.

Comment: Certainly  "20130321 28:12:53" is *not* an acceptable value. You are not receiving an invalid format error, but a value error. Why are you expecting the time to 28 hours, 12 minutes, 53 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to do this:

```
db.prepare('statement1', "INSERT INTO games (game_hash,team1,team2,team1score,team2score,time,update_at) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6, now())");
db.exec_prepared('statement1', [myId, team1, team1score, team2, team2score, progress]);
```

Saves you a line of code, and a significant number of things that can go wrong.

Now if that doesn't fix the problem check for triggers.  If it does fix the problem, maybe it was a typo, reserved word, or the like.  If it doesn't fix the problem then something else is messing with the data between your insert statement and the storage of the row.

Comment: The `now()` function mentioned in this comment was the key for my problem.